# Why is my website displaying <ul> and <li> in the dom

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, html-lists

I'm trying to display cards in my dom but in the text im showing there is some code as shown in the picture below

```
<div class="app">
  <h1> All Fishes and Their Photos</h1>
  <ul v-for="(fish, i) in fishes" :key="i" />
  <li>
    <div class="maincontainer">
      <div class="back">
        <p>{{fish['Biology']}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="front">
        <div class="image">
          <img :src="fish['Species Illustration Photo'].src" />
          <h2>{{ fish['Species Name']}}</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: i did mention doctype html in the top

Comment: `<ul v-for="(fish, i) in fishes" :key="i"/>` you close the `ul` tag, leave it open: `<ul v-for="(fish, i) in fishes" :key="i">`.  Edit: and `<ul>` shouldn't be used in a `<p>` tag.

Comment: Consider using ESlint to catch those kind of small errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `'/'` you have at the end of the first `<ul>` tag, this should fix the problem, but also consider using the v-for on the `<li>` tag, and not the `<ul>` tag as
the element that must be repeated many times is `<li>`.